# Ajax Json Cross Domains in phonegap

Tags: android, ajax, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have a problem with AJax/Json petitions with PhoneGap. I have this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Cartelera</title>

<meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <title>
    </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="my.css" />
    <style>
        /* App custom styles */
    </style>
    <script src="cordova-2.0.0.js">
    </script>
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <script src="js/jquery.mobile.js">
    </script>
    <script src="my.js">  
    </script>

    <script>

    $(document).ready(function(){

        $.support.cors = true;
        $.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages = true;

        //$("#ulCartelera").append('<li><a href="app.html" data-transition="slide" text="hola" > Prueba 1 </a></li>');
        //$("#ulCartelera").append('<li><a href="app.html" data-transition="slide" text="hola" > Prueba 2 </a></li>');
        $('#cargaDiv').html('<img src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.mobile/1.1.1/images/ajax-loader.gif" /> Cargando...'); // Loading message


        $.getJSON("http://www.cinesimf.com/rss/JSONTorrevieja.php",
                function(data){

            for (i=0;i<data.length;i++)
                {

                $("#ulCartelera").append('<li><a href="app.html" data-transition="slide" text="hola" >'+data[i].titulo+'</a></li>');

                }
            $('#cargaDiv').html(''); //Remove Loading message
            $("#ulCartelera").listview('refresh');      
        })


    })
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div data-role="page" id="cartelerafinestrat">
<div data-role="header">
<a href="app.html" data-icon="delete" data-transition="flow">Atras</a>
<h1>IMF Finestrat</h1>
</div>
<div id="cargaDiv">

</div>
<div id="cartelera">
<ul id="ulCartelera" data-role="listview" class="ui-listview" data-theme="d" data_dividertheme="b">


</ul>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
</pre>
```

I have added in config.xml (/res/xml/) my domain ("http://www.cinesimf.com/*") in the phonegap whitelist.

If I try the code in a navigator in my pc, it works OK, but in Android aplication nevers load.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem depends on a general webkit (and modern browsers) issue.
If you want to do a json request to a cross-domain server you have to modify your manifest file on Android or your plist file non Iphone, inserting the allowed domains where you want to get your data. 
You could also do a jsonp request to avoid manifests updates:

```
$.getJSON("http://www.cinesimf.com/rss/JSONTorrevieja.php?callback=?",
            function(data){

         for (i=0;i<data.length;i++)
            {

            $("#ulCartelera").append('<li><a href="app.html" data-transition="slide" text="hola" >'+data[i].titulo+'</a></li>');

            }
        $('#cargaDiv').html(''); //Remove Loading message
        $("#ulCartelera").listview('refresh');      
    })
```

You can have a good explanation about jsonp there: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-aj-jsonp1/